# Relative time - how to calculate difference beween post publish date and current time

Tags: date-time, timestamp

I want to calculate the difference between post's publishing time and current time, and I want to read that value as a number (number of hours, minutes, seconds whatever, i just want it to be a number).

The reason is I want to do something depending on the post's age.

Would this code work?

```
$date = get_post_time('G', true, $post);
$current_time = current_time( 'mysql', $gmt = 0 );
$newer_date = strtotime( $current_time );

$postsage = $newer_date - $date;

if($postsage < 7200){
    ...
} 
// if post is between one and two hours old
else if (($postsage >= 7200) && ($postsage <=14400)){ 
   ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

Is this code bit valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print relative time on posts automatically we can use `get_the_date` filter. We will check the time difference and print it in human readable form.

```
// Relative date & time
function wp_relative_date() {
  return human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) . ' ago';
}
add_filter( 'get_the_date', 'wp_relative_date' ); // for posts
add_filter( 'get_comment_date', 'wp_relative_date' ); // for comments
```

And in your theme use `<?php echo get_the_date(); ?>` to print relative time.

If you do not need relative time for comments then remove following from code.

```
add_filter( 'get_comment_date', 'wp_relative_date' ); // for comments
```

**EDIT**

To get time difference in seconds. Use this.

```
$seconds = current_time( 'timestamp' ) - get_the_time('U');
```

Now you can use `$seconds` in your if conditions.

Comment: I don't want to print the time difference, i want to know what it is, check it in my code, and depending on the value, do something.

If the difference between publishing date and current time is, for example, 6 hours or 10800 seconds, I want to know a way to calculate that, so I can 'ask' in my code if(time < 10800){do something} else {do something else 2 }

Comment: You can use `$seconds = current_time( 'timestamp' ) - get_the_time('U');` to get time difference in seconds. Check edit

Comment: Yep, the `$seconds = current_time( 'timestamp' ) - get_the_time('U');` does the job. Thanks for the help ;)